# Bigquery: Using ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN in an array of ST_GEOGPOINT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, geolocation

I want to use ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN to cluster geopoints.
The example in Bigquery page is this one:

```
WITH Geos as
  (SELECT 1 as row_id, st_geogfromtext('point empty') as geo UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, st_geogfromtext('multipoint(1 1, 2 2, 4 4, 5 2)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, st_geogfromtext('point(14 15)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, st_geogfromtext('linestring(40 1, 42 34, 44 39)') UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, st_geogfromtext('polygon((40 2, 40 1, 41 2, 40 2))'))
SELECT row_id, geo, ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN(geo, 1e5, 1) OVER () AS cluster_num FROM
Geos ORDER BY row_id
+--------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| row_id |                geo                | cluster_num |
+--------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
|      1 |          GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY |        NULL |
|      2 |    MULTIPOINT(1 1, 2 2, 5 2, 4 4) |           0 |
|      3 |                      POINT(14 15) |           1 |
|      4 |    LINESTRING(40 1, 42 34, 44 39) |           2 |
|      5 | POLYGON((40 2, 40 1, 41 2, 40 2)) |           2 |
+--------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
```

In my code I have a Array of points that I aggregate together.
However it seems to no work eventhout I see in the results as MULTIPOINT.

my code:

```
    ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN(ST_UNION_AGG(buyer_geo_point), 1e4, 2) OVER () AS cluster_num ,
    ST_UNION_AGG(buyer_geo_point)
```

The results are either null or have completely wrong values:

```
null
POINT(-41.5320687976469 -20.3600487114797)

null
MULTIPOINT(-39.0833794 -5.9597183, -39.00682744 -5.73228798)

null
POINT(-40.224447061747 -17.3677128083793)

null
POINT(-40.10711168 -18.08920528)
32  
null
POINT(-41.10854564 -21.47675214)

null
POINT(-51.11207578 -20.64520046)

117
MULTIPOINT(-38.08106136 -11.94490164, -38.06814822 -11.94196154)
    
117
MULTIPOINT(-38.07860266 -11.94484066, -38.0786308 -11.9448231, -38.0787098 -11.9447567, -38.0786912 -11.9447861, -38.0676091 -11.9453678)

null
MULTIPOINT(-39.98731268 -14.8426174, -39.98782804 -14.84623434)
```

UPDATE:
I figure out a solution to have the points on each cluster labeled.

```
WITH  merchant_cluster as (SELECT  
        pl_gl.merchant_id, 
        ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN(buyer_geo_point, 1e3, 1) OVER (Partition by merchant_id) as clusters ,
        buyer_geo_point
    FROM `geo-info-table` as geo
    LEFT JOIN `merchants-table` as m on geo.merchant_id = m.user_id
    LEFT JOIN `adresses-table` as add on m.user_id = add.user_id
)
SELECT merchant_id, STRUCT(ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(clusters,-1)) as cluster_id, ARRAY_AGG(buyer_geo_point) as point) FROM merchant_cluster 
GROUP BY merchant_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
select cluster_num, ST_UNION_AGG(buyer_geo_point) geo_cluster 
from (
  select buyer_geo_point,
    ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN(buyer_geo_point, 1e4, 2) OVER () AS cluster_num
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
group by cluster_num
```

I tried to mimic your data using points exposed in your question and got below result using above code (note - I used ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN(buyer_geo_point, 200000, 1) because of very small set of points)

[image]

Below is visualization of this result - each cluster assigned separate color

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to discover clusters and have each point flaged with a cluster id.

Comment: I figured out how to do it with the help of one college. I will update my question with the solution.

Comment: Your solution works, and is similar to our own. The difference was that I need to join for each merchant, so it needed OVER (Partition by merchant_id). I would like to understand why my first approach wasn't working.

Comment: PS: what is the map visualization tool you are using?

Comment: This is Goliath – not just visualization tool - rather the IDE for BigQuery – part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio). Another tool in this suite is Magnus - Workflow Automator. Supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and more with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc.
Disclosure: I am creator of those tools and leader on Potens team (see it in my SO Profile)